# Splitting a file into an array in Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to split a file into an array.

```
Structure Users
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Surname As String
    Dim Address As String
    Dim AccountNo As String
    Dim PIN As String
    Dim Balance As Decimal
End Structure
```

This is the structure I need filled with a `XSL` file; it can be changed to a `CSV` easily.
I just need help splitting this file into the structure.

```
Sub LoadDatabase(ByRef Accounts() As Users, ByVal lineCount As Integer)
    Dim file(lineCount) As Users

    FileOpen(1, "Database.xsl", OpenMode.Input)
    file = Input(LOF(1), 1)

    For i = 1 To lineCount
        Accounts(i).Name = Split(file(i), ",")
    Next

    FileClose(1)
End Sub
```

The Excel file looks like this:

[image]

Comment: If only there was a way for us to know what the file actually looked like.

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/52JNxyP

Comment: If you want to import it from CSV, you could use the `TextFieldParser` class (though I'm sure there are FOSS and commercial CSV libraries available too).  If you want to import it from a spreadsheet, you could convert it to `xlsx` and then use the Open XML SDK package (`DocumentFormat.OpenXml`) to read it.  If you want to stick with the original format, I'm sure there are a number of commercial libraries that support the loading of `xsl` files.

Comment: You tagged your code as vb.net. Actually that's predominantly pre ".NET code".